# Gatsby StaticImage trouble

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby for the first time and I can't figure out why my StaticImage tag (which is currently commented out) throws me an error message. I'm using Slick Carousel for React, and a regular img tag works just fine. Any advice?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import  StaticImage  from "gatsby-plugin-image";
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css'
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css'
import TestImage from "../../images/testImage.png"

export default class AutoPlay extends Component {
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      speed: 5000,
      autoplaySpeed: 0,
      cssEase: "linear"
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <img src={TestImage}></img>
            {/* <StaticImage src={TestImage} alt=""/> */}
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the error I get thrown:
[image: RunTime Error]

I've read up on StaticImage for a couple days, and my best guess is there is something in the Carousel that makes the image dynamic.

Comment: Try to wrap StaticImage in curly braces in import like that: `import  { StaticImage }  from "gatsby-plugin-image";`

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Note that errors and other text must not be presented as images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the path as a string for the src attribute instead of passing an imported element:

src='../path'

Instead of:

import el from '../path';
src={el}